# Best factory implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

So because I'm currently reading into design patters I have a "newbie" and at least for me interesting question to ask.

What Factory implementation is the best? I've seen factories where the create method is hardcoded and if a new subtype is added I'll need to edit the method. For example:

```
public class ProductFactory{
    public Product createProduct(String ProductID){
        if (id==ID1)
            return new OneProduct();
        if (id==ID2) return
            return new AnotherProduct();
        ... // so on for the other Ids

        return null; //if the id doesn't have any of the expected values
    }
    ...
}
```

This seems to be the implementation that takes the lowest amount of resources. But furthemore I've seen implementations that use reflection:

```
class ProductFactory
{
    private HashMap<String, Class> m_RegisteredProducts = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerProduct (String productID, Class productClass)
    {
        m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, productClass);
    }

    public Product createProduct(String productID)
    {
        Class productClass = (Class)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID);
        Constructor productConstructor = cClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
        return (Product)productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { });
    }
}
```

Which seems to be the slowest one because it is using reflection to work. And the last implementation seems to take the most RAM because it has an extra instance of a specific class stored.

```
class ProductFactory
{
    private HashMap<String, Product> m_RegisteredProducts = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerProduct(String productID, Product p)    {
        m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, p);
    }

    public Product createProduct(String productID){
        ((Product)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID)).createProduct();
    }
}
```

Product classes for the last factory:

```
abstract class Product
{
    public abstract Product createProduct();
    ...
}

class OneProduct extends Product
{
    ...
    static
    {
        ProductFactory.instance().registerProduct("ID1", new OneProduct());
    }
    public OneProduct createProduct()
    {
        return new OneProduct();
    }
    ...
}
```

Both the second last and last implementation allow to register new products without modifying the factory class in for example a static block in the to be registered product extending/implementing class. Is this better? And if so, which of those two implementation is the better one? Or is the hard coded implementation better because it seems to require less resources.

Comment: There is no free lunch in CS, i.e. there is not really a _best_ solution. Like you said, there are pros and cons to each, and it depends on the situation which one is the most suitable.

Comment: You might look at a way it's been done by some very smart folks. This is often a good way to get started. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject

Comment: As stated above, it all bogs down to the concrete details in each situation. I would *generally* favor the first approach, because I tend to prefer to keep magic going out in the code to the absolute minimum -- if later on I decide to remove `OneProduct`, I like the IDE/compiler to be able to flag that to me. But I do understand that if you start having dozens or even hundreds of products, maybe something reflection based might well prove to be more maintainable (either by documenting that behavior or even having unit-tests in place).

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1) Parametrized Factory implementation. Overtime we create a new Product object we have to modify the Factory.

Approach 2) We dont need to modify the Factory in order to add a new implementation. In addition the factory needs to know in advance all the available classes in order to begin instantiating them. Performance is not a factor here because on a modern JVM the performance loss from reflection will be negligible.

Approach 3)If I understand correctly the Product is exposing a factory method. Each implementation of Product through Polymorphism is responsible for providing logic for instance creation. Although I dont get it how you will use exactly a non static method. And if you use static you loose your Polymorphism. Approach 3 is not very clear to me. Is the Product actually a Wrapper around the real Product ?

Approach number 1 is least flexible

Comment: Thanks for your help but that's basicly the same I already stated above. The question is which one to use and which one is the most efficient one in terms of performance, work and readability.

Comment: We you have not said that Approach number two does not have to edit the Factory.  Anyway I will say something more. You should not be concerned about the speed when it comes to reflection. The difference in speed when it comes to the modern Jvms is negligible. When it comes to your last implementation I dont see how you are going to make it with a non static method. And if you use a static method you will loose your Polymorphism

Comment: I am not sure I understand ((Product)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID)).createProduct(); Are you providing a Factory inside a Factory ? How will this work exactly ?

Comment: Or is your product actually a Wrapper around the real product ?

Comment: I edited the post above to feature an example of the product classes for that case.

Comment: You actually dont need to create the Istance 2 times. If you know that you always use the createProduct method you can just register the Class like in Approach number 2. Creating a real instance of Product just to expose the create method. I dont think this is good

Comment: As stated by Alex, I wouldn't worry too much about the performance implications of using reflection. Unless this specific factory is being used millions of times, you shouldn't really care.